# Use td-value as tr-class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I want to give table rows the class of one of the cells, like this:

I have this table,

```
<table id="mytable">
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Favorite color</th>
 </tr>
  <td>James</td>
  <td>red</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>blue</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and I want it to end up like this.

```
<table id="mytable">
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Favorite color</th>
 </tr>
 <tr class="red">
  <td>James</td>
  <td>red</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="blue">
  <td>John</td>
  <td>blue</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `addClass` method:

```
$('tbody tr').addClass(function(){
    return $('td:last', this).text()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SwELe/

Please note that you are missing opening `tr` tag before `<td>James</td>`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTML you have there:

```
$("tr:not(:first)").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass($(this).children("td").last().text());
});
```

## jsFiddle <sub>(aka. example)</sub>

What this does:

- [$](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) = The shorthand symbol for *jQuery*
- [("tr](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) = Beginning of a jQuery Selector, in this case we are starting at tag `tr`
- [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) = This tells our selector **not** to select what is coming in parenthesis
- [(:first)](http://api.jquery.com/first/) = This is the parameter of `:not`, in this case were telling it we don't want the first element in the overall element selection
- [.each(](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) = this jQuery function acts like a For Loop on the elements that have been selected

  - jQuery Object's are 0 Index based (meaning it starts at 0 and counts up)
- [function(i)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) { = This is the beginning of our `callback` function for the .each call. The `i` represents the index of each element as it is passed through
- [$(this)](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/) = This jQuery selector is grabbing the current element in the loop
- [addClass(](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) = this jQuery function allows us to add class names to elements
- [$(this)](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/) = again, referring to current element being manipulated
- [.children("td")](http://api.jquery.com/children/) = Since the current element is a TR, then we know its children should be `td`'s, thus we use the child selector to grab those children
- [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) = this tells our selector that we only want the **last** element in the object collection
- [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) = this tells our selector that we want the text of the element selected
- ); }); = simply close everything out!